# create shopping cart price rules based on store view

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, store-view, discount

Is there any way we can create shopping cart price rules based on store-views.

discount should apply only for particular store views ?

Comment: This one is available but paid http://bsscommerce.com/shopping-cart-rules-per-store-view.html

Comment: @AshishMadankar Thanks for this. we will take this as final option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there's no DEFAULT way for this. Though you can do this **per website** because the price can be set on a Global or Website level only.

But there is an option that you can think of:

**You can create websites equals to the no. of stores and assign one store per one website**.

Then update OR assign your catalog (I mean, products) according to NEWLY created websites. Or you can do "Change attributes" to update all/multiple products.

Then assign you Shopping Cart Rule to appropriate Websites.

Comment: which is having more advantages - websites or stores , also please check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112865/site-for-multi-countires-multiple-websites-or-multiple-stores)

Answer (score 1):

Price is a global attribute. Correspondingly, price rules are also created on a website level. In this case, a product can't have various prices per store views. Magento works in this way.